# $(x-4)^2+8|x-4|+15=0$

Tags: quadratics

> The sum of the roots of the equation $(x-4)^2+8|x-4|+15=0$ is

My attempt: Let $|x-4|=y$. So, the equation becomes $y^2+8y+15=0$. So, $y=-3,-5$. Both values should be rejected as $|x-4|$ cannot be negative. But the answer has been given as $16$.

Comment: I think you're working too hard. $(x-4)^2\ge0$, $8|x-4|\ge0$, $15>0$, so the equation can't have any solutions. If someone has asked you to solve this problem, I advise you to ask them to clarify. (But first check to see whether you have copied it down correctly.)

Comment: I have copied the statement correctly. But I see your point, it should be clear at the beginning itself that the equation has no solutions.

Comment: Your answer is correct as well. As stated it has no solutions. You can plug in $x=16$ and see that it doesn't solve the equation.

Comment: @quarague, $16$ is the sum of roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the answer has been given as $16$, I think that the equation should read

$$(x-4)^2-8|x-4|+15=0.$$

Now let $y:=|x-4|$ and proceed as above.

Comment: Thanks @Fred. I'll correct the statement in the book.